# Pandas plot gives correct plot, whereas matplotlib gives error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot, python-datetime

I have a dataset, where I am trying to visualize data against `date-time`. I converted string of date-time into `date-time` format by

```
 dataset = pd.read_csv('price.csv')
 dataset2=dataset[['Date','MCP']]
 dataset2['Date']=pd.to_datetime(dataset2['Date'])
```

Now plotting in `matplotlib`

```
dataset2.plot()
```

[image: correct plot]

but for the same, `matplotlib`

```
plt.plot(dataset2.index,dataset2['MCP'])
```

[image: wrong plot]

Can someone explain to me what is happening? Am I converting `string` to `date-time` using the wrong method or something else?

Comment: We don't even know how the data looks like. But I guess the problem is that it is not sorted ascendingly.

Comment: Sorry, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I will post a snapshot of data but, it was sorted in a continuous manner. The problem was with the format of date-time. At the end of one day, it used to consider 'day' part as the month and stretched it all along till the next month. I will edit my solution to include the problem explanation in detail. So if you could then help why matplotlib considered it in that manner and pandas interpret it correctly

Comment: I still thing that the problem is caused by unsorted data. Of course this could be caused by it not being read in correctly. Without a [mcve] of the data (not the actual data, but some data to reproduce the issue), I don't think one can help further.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem, But if someone could explain the reason

```
dataset2['Date']=pd.to_datetime(dataset2['Date']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
dataset2['Date']=pd.to_datetime(dataset2['Date'])
```

Pandas by default converts it into different format so I have to convert it back to string with right format acceptable by matplotlib and then convert string again to date-time. Is there any other way to do it?

```
plt.plot(dataset2['Date'],dataset2['MCP'])
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what matplotlib interpreted and here it is:
After just simple conversion to date-time using

```
dataset2['Date']=pd.to_datetime(dataset2['Date'])
```

[image: snapshot of data]

Taking the first 96 values(after which the date changes) it works as it should.
But after that(Taking values for next day and so on) It considers 'Day' part of time-stamp as month and stretches days till next month(till that particular value occurs).

[image: erroneous plot]

P.S.- Had to write as the second answer because not allowed to embed more than 2 images till reputation 10